# FusionCharts labels disappear when using the javascript fallback charts

Tags: label, fusioncharts

I am using the commercial version of fusion charts 3.

When rendered in Flash my charts look perfect.

But when I disable flash in my browser, the chart is rendering but my x-axis labels are not showing.

If anyone can point me to a helpful resource or give me a bit of direction, it is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem would not occur with version v3.2.1 or later of FusionCharts. Please verify that you have this version.